# Do we take questions on "helper" programs?

Tags: discussion, questions

We're an Emacs Q&A site, but there's a grey area (to me, at least)
about questions on external programs that are closely related to
our use of Emacs, but which are not actually Emacs.  In effect,
I'm referring to "helper" programs that we use only to make our
experience with Emacs better.

The immediate examples that spring to mind are programs used to
make interacting with email more productive.  Let's say the
ultimate goal is a working `gnus` setup: everything about the question is in
pursuit of that.  There are lots of blog posts about setting up `gnus`
with `offlineimap`, `mbsync`, and `dovecot`, but many of those
posts would be semi-unreadable to a user with minimal experience
editing configuration files (or even with a fair amount -- I never
figured out `dovecot`).

Would questions on setting up these helper programs be on-topic
here?  It's iffy -- hence the question.  Do we:

- Take helper-program questions here as long as they're clearly
  questions about getting an Emacs ecosystem set up, or
- Send people over to stackoverflow?

Related threads:

- [This meta post](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/276/253)
  from a while back argues that configuring non-Emacs programs
  should be off-topic.
- Another thread
  ([Questions where Emacs is only incidental](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74/questions-where-emacs-is-only-incidental))
  from the early days of the site suggested that they're borderline
  questions, with some folks leaning off-topic and some leaning in
  favor of inclusiveness on questions.

Comment: Imo it really depends on the question. Do you have a specific example in mind?

Comment: @T.Verron: to extend the email example, consider an example like "I'm trying to set up `gnus` with `offlineimap` and `dovecot` as suggested on *site X*.  I'm most of the way there but am stuck on the `dovecot` part.  How do I get `dovecot` working?"  Strictly speaking, such a question would be about `dovecot` and not Emacs, but since the spirit of the question is "how to set up the Emacs tool chain to do *x*," it's not clear if we do (should?) take such questions here.

Comment: If the answer is the same if we remove emacs from the question (and the question still makes sense), I don't think that it is emacs-related. You can do almost (citation needed) everything with emacs, this website is not about everything. But I was asking if you had an example of an existing question... Maybe we should wait until the problem arises before worrying about it?

Comment: Here's an example of some external but related software: `stumpwm`.  I think questions about getting `stumpwm` to talk to emacs would likely be valid.  (The intersection of `stumpwm` users and emacs users approaches the set of `stumpwm` users, right?)