# Are questions about the "Emacs toolchain" acceptable?

Tags: discussion, questions

are questions about programs from the "Emacs toolchain" allowed?  Specifically, would a question about Texinfo be acceptable, given that it's a standard format for writing Emacs documentation?

I found [Do we take questions on "helper" programs?](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308/do-we-take-questions-on-helper-programs) which has no answer, but seems to imply that the scope of this site be limited strictly to Emacs.

What is the "official" position?  Where can I read about it?

Comment: There is no official position. As a baseline, I would consider it on-topic as long as you're trying to use that helper program as part of the Emacs toolchain (as in, you're compiling documentation for an Emacs package). That's kind of a bad criteria, but it's the best I can come up with.

Comment: What @Malabarba said.